# how do i make a response bot not keep responding?

Tags: javascript

Let's assume i have a bot sitting at a chat window that always grabs the innerHTML of the last comment sent element on a page as follows:

```
setInterval(function() {
   var comment = document.querySelector('div[name="UserComment"]').innerHTML;
   if (comment.includes('Hello!')) {
      document.querySelector('input[aria-label="SendComment"]').value = 'Hi!!!!';
      document.getElementById('submitComment').click();
   }
}, 100);
```

The above works just fine barring the fact that it will infinitely reply. I had pondered adding the comment to an array and checking against that but something tells me there's a more elegant way.

Comment: The only two ways that I can think of is storing past responses or scanning the DOM every time looking for past comments. So storing in an array seems like the most efficient method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the content to which has been already replied as a property of the `UserComment` element and only reply if the content of the `UserCOmment` field has been changed

```
setInterval(function() {
   var comment = document.querySelector('div[name="UserComment"]').innerHTML;
   // Store comment as property of the UserComment element
   document.querySelector('div[name="UserComment"]').prop("lastValue", comment);
   // Check for content in comment   and verify that the content is different  to the last comment which has been automatically answered before sending a response
   if (comment.includes('Hello!') && comment != document.querySelector('div[name="UserComment"]').prop("lastValue")) {
      document.querySelector('input[aria-label="SendComment"]').value = 'Hi!!!!';
      document.getElementById('submitComment').click();
   }
}, 100);
```